# How can I most effectively capture & handle all cases of user interaction with this form element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm struggling to solve a design problem with my lackluster JavaScript skills. I have a product configuration form for ordering a custom product - most of the form elements have a static price, which is either added or subtracted to/from the total as they are checked/unchecked. The last element, which is a delivery mileage, is a dynamic number that the user inputs and either checks/unchecks that they want it included. I'm struggling to find the best way to arrange the logic for this. What I tried previously would update correctly if you entered the mileage and then checked the box, but if you checked first and entered the mileage after it would not capture. So I tried an on-blur event capture instead, but this breaks when you check the box, enter a mileage, blur, then change the mileage and blur again - it adds again.

This is my logic for the whole form (short script) and relevant HTML:

```js
let total = 12000;
const mileageElem = document.getElementById('delivery-mileage');
let updateVal = 0;

document.getElementById('delivery-mileage').addEventListener('blur', function () {
  const check = document.getElementById('delivery');
    let mileage = mileageElem.value;
        if (parseInt(mileage, 10) >= 0) {
        if (check.checked) {
          total += parseInt(mileage, 10)
        } else {
          total -= parseInt(mileage, 10)
        }
  }
  document.getElementById('total-cost').innerHTML = `$${total.toLocaleString("en-US")}.00`;
});

[...document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input has-value')].forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       if (e.target.id == "delivery"){
    //     let mileage = mileageElem.value;
    //     if (parseInt(mileage, 10) >= 0) {
    //     if (e.target.checked) {
    //       updateVal = mileageElem.value;
    //       total += parseInt(updateVal, 10)
    //     } else {
    //       total -= parseInt(updateVal, 10)
    //     }
    //   }
     }
       else{
        if (e.target.checked) {
          total += parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
        } else {
          total -= parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
        }
     }
    document.getElementById('total-cost').innerHTML = `$${total.toLocaleString("en-US")}.00`
  })

});


document.addEventListener('click', e=> {
  console.log(e.target);

})
```

```html
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="max-width: 1000px;">
      <input class="form-check-input has-value" type="checkbox" name="delivery" id="delivery">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="delivery">Delivery to a distance of...<p class="price">$1/mile</p></label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="delivery-mileage" placeholder="Miles to deliver" style = "width: 200px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="max-width: 1000px;">
    <h2 id="total">Total Cost: <span id="total-cost">$12,000.00</span> plus tax</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-4 mx-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success text-nowrap" type="button">Let's Go!</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, you will need to keep a separate variable for delivery charges:

```js
let total = 12000;
let delivery = 0;
let updateVal = 0;
const inputBox = document.querySelector('#delivery-mileage');
const check = document.querySelector("#delivery");
const totalBox = document.getElementById('total-cost');

inputBox.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  let mileage = event.target.value;
  delivery = 0;
  if (+mileage >= 0) {
    if (check.checked) {
      delivery = +mileage;
    }
  }
  totalBox.innerHTML = `$${(total+delivery).toLocaleString("en-US")}.00`;
});

check.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  delivery = 0;
  if (e.target.checked) {
    delivery = +inputBox.value;
  }
  totalBox.innerHTML = `$${(total+delivery).toLocaleString("en-US")}.00`
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="max-width: 1000px;">
    <input class="form-check-input has-value" type="checkbox" name="delivery" id="delivery">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="delivery">Delivery to a distance of...<p class="price">$1/mile</p></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="delivery-mileage" placeholder="Miles to deliver" style="width: 200px;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm" style="max-width: 1000px;">
    <h2 id="total">Total Cost: <span id="total-cost">$12,000.00</span> plus tax</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-4 mx-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success text-nowrap" type="button">Let's Go!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this method with minor modifications and was successful, also factoring out the DOM update string into its own function to call in each of the other situational cases. This way its consistent about exactly how it updates the DOM, adding delivery and total together each time.